# How to solve that logarithmic equation?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, symbolic

I mean an equation
$$ \log _{2 \sqrt{\sqrt{3}+2}}\left(x^2-2 x-2\right)=\log _{\sqrt{3}+2}\left(x^2-2 x-3\right).$$

The result of

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; Reduce[Log[2*Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[3]], x^2 - 2 x - 2] == 
Log[2 + Sqrt[3], x^2 - 2 x - 3], x, Reals]
```

> `x == Root[{(Log[2] + Log[2 + Sqrt[3]]/2)*Log[-3 - 2*#1 + #1^2] -  Log[2 + Sqrt[3]]*Log[-2 - 2*#1 + #1^2] & ,  -3.234170902346232549156572876357812204797}] ||  x == Root[{(Log[2] + Log[2 + Sqrt[3]]/2)*Log[-3 - 2*#1 + #1^2] -  Log[2 + Sqrt[3]]*Log[-2 - 2*#1 + #1^2] & ,  5.2341709023462325491515728763578122314}]`

is numeric whereas the roots can be expressed symbolically.

```
FullSimplify[Log[2*Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[3]], x^2 - 2 x - 2] == 
Log[2 + Sqrt[3], x^2 - 2 x - 3] /. x -> 1 + Sqrt[11 + 4*Sqrt[3]]]
```

> `True`

and

```
FullSimplify[Log[2*Sqrt[2 + Sqrt[3]], x^2 - 2 x - 2] == 
Log[2 + Sqrt[3], x^2 - 2 x - 3] /. x -> 1 - Sqrt[11 + 4*Sqrt[3]]]
```

> `True`

Is there a way to find symbolic solutions?

Comment: Please do not use the [tag:bugs] tags for your _own_ questions. See the tag description. Wait until someone confirms the bug and adds the tag.

Comment: It's very hard to visually follow the inputs you are showing. Can you assign parts of the expressions to variables, and rewrite everything in terms of those, to make it clear what you are showing? Don't keep writing out the full equation many times without good reason. We can't see if it's really the same equation or not.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Sorry, don't understand. Could you present an example of such change? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 your first and second equations aren't even the same. The first one starts with `2*Log[2...`, the second one with `Log[2*...` . Put that leading `2` back, and all the True's become False which is consistent with the first reduce. No bug here.

Comment: @flinty's comment illustrates perfectly what I meant in both comments. If you had written, "With `eq = ...`, `Reduce[eq, x]` gives no solutions but `eq /. x -> r` returns `True`", it would have been much easier to follow what you were doing, and you would not have made a mistake.

Comment: @flinty: Thank you. fixed. Sorry for the bad copy&paste. Do you notice more typos?

Comment: "Do you notice more typos?" Yes. There is no more evidence of a problem. Please re-evaluate the corrected inputs, and let the morning coffee kick in :P ;) Now the outputs are `False` instead of `True` (second input onwards).

Comment: @Szabolcs: Hope now is OK.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I don't find [in Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%3A+P+%3B%29&ei=hPxuYYvVPMnykwXF3JuABw&ved=0ahUKEwiLp5Gl_NbzAhVJ-aQKHUXuBnAQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%3A+P+%3B%29&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyBAgAEBMyCAgAEBYQHhATMggIABAWEB4QEzIICAAQFhAeEBMyCAgAEBYQHhATMggIABAWEB4QEzIICAAQFhAeEBMyCAgAEBYQHhATOgcIABBHELADOggIABAHEB4QE0oECEEYAFDn8AVYwfYFYOPOCmgCcAJ4AIABogOIAfwGkgEJMC4xLjEuMC4xmAEAoAEByAEIwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz) what :P ;) means. Could you explain it? TIA.

Comment: @user64494 https://www.emoticonr.com/emoticons/frustrated-tongue

Comment: Can moderators explain why the question was closed?  Typos were corrected and the edited question was answered. TIA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not foolproof, but [`RootApproximant`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RootApproximant) works for this case:

```
sol = Solve[Log[2*Sqrt[2+Sqrt[3]],x^2-2 x-2]==Log[2+Sqrt[3],x^2-2 x-3],x,Reals] //Values;
ToRadicals@RootApproximant[sol]
```

> {{1 - Sqrt[11 + 4 Sqrt[3]]}, {1 + Sqrt[11 + 4 Sqrt[3]]}}

Comment: +1. Thank you. As I understand it, `RootApproximant` produces only a a guess.

Comment: Do you mean "whole" instead of "fool"? TIA and deepregard.

Comment: Having the answer in hand, it's not hard to verify (`sol - ans // FullSimplify`).

Comment: @MichaelE2: A clever move. Thank you. I am able to present a lot of trigonometric equations where `Reduce` produces numerical solutions instead of symbolic ones. I am not sure whether `RootApproximant` works in that situations.

Comment: I accept your answer together with the valuable MiichaelE2's comment which finishes the work.